# How do I re-enable the "Safe to Remove Device" message after ejecting an USB drive on Windows 10 home, x64, Version 2004

Tags: windows-10, notifications

When I go to taskbar, push the thumb drive icon to eject the drive, I do not receive the "Safe to Remove" message. How can I re-enable that notification? Windows 10 Home, x64, Version 2004

Comment: After many attempts to fix that issue, I've switched to a free, more reliable, third party tool,, HotSwap, http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm . There are many similar applications, https://alternativeto.net/software/hotswap/ , implying the issue is long-standing.

Comment: Perhaps check the settings in Control Panel, AutoPlay.  At the bottom, click on Reset all Defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific answer to your question, but it may reveal that you do not need an answer:

1. Open Disk Management (Win + x then press k)
2. Right click on your ejectable drive
3. Select properties from the drop-down menu
4. Open the Hardware tab
5. Left click on your ejectable drive in the list to highlight it
6. Click on properties at the bottom of the menu
7. Open the Policies tab
8. Observe the removal policy

Specifically, if you are using the Quick removal policy (one which I would recommend not turning off),  you do not need to eject the drive at all because write caching is disabled.

There are a couple of reasons you may still want your notification:

1. If you're not using the Quick removal policy
2. If you'd like a prompt to tell you when your files have finished transferring.

However, I think this may help many future users concerned about the notification.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Settings`.
2. Tap `Apps`.
3. Tap `Default Apps.`
4. Scroll down and Tap `Set Default By App.`
5. Scroll down and Tap `Safely Remove Device.`
6. Tap `Manage` when it appears.
7. Tap `Safely Remove Device.`
   Nothing happened on the screen when I did step 7,
   but I got the `Safely Remove Device` notification back
   the next time I wanted to remove a flashdrive.